# Angular2 subcomponent html not refreshed after load?

Tags: angular, typescript

First, I am new to angular2, so sorry if it's a trivial question. I am trying to put some code in a sub component. I tried many things but it seems I can't figure this one out.

I am trying to get some results from json using http get and subscribe. My understanding is that the data is loaded after the view is created. I am able to see the data in my view but whenever I try to put the code in charge of displaying the data in a component. It's not working.

I was able to display the data by putting the ngFor outside the found-items component and displaying one item in the subcomponent. But I really would like to understand why I am not able to display the data when I transfer an array to the subcomponent.

It seems to me that angular doesn't detect change in my subcomponent because my array is not defined when the page first load.

All the code is available on [GitHub](https://github.com/mikrethor/coursera-angular2/tree/master/module3-solution).

My parent component HTML code is as follow :

```html
<div class="container">
    <h1>Narrow Down Your Chinese Menu Choice</h1>
    <div class="form-group">
      <input type="text" placeholder="search term" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="searchTerm">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group narrow-button">
      <button class="btn btn-primary" (click)="narrowItDown()">Narrow It Down For Me!</button>
    </div>
<ol>
   <li *ngFor="let item of menuItems; let i = index; ">
       {{ item.short_name }} : {{ item.name }} : {{ item.description }}
      <button (click)="remove(i)">Don't want this one!</button>
   </li> 
</ol>
<found-items [items]='menuItems'></found-items>
</div>
```

The component found-items is not displaying anything. But the app-component is.

My parent component TS code is as follow :

```js
import {Component,Output,OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {MenuSearchService,MenuItem} from '../../services/menu-search-service';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Rx';
import { FoundItemsComponent }  from '../../components/founditems/founditems.component';

@Component({
    selector: 'narrow-application',
    templateUrl: `app/components/application/app.html`,
})
export class NarrowItDownComponent {
   @Output() menuItems:MenuItem[];
   searchTerm:string="";
    constructor(private menuSearchService: MenuSearchService) { 
     }
    public getMatchedMenuItems(searchTerm:string){
       return this.menuSearchService.getMatchedMenuItems(searchTerm);  
    }

    public narrowItDown(){
        console.log("searchTerm:"+this.searchTerm)
        this.menuItems=this.getMatchedMenuItems(this.searchTerm);
    }

     public remove(index:number){
        console.log("index: "+index)
       this.menuItems.splice(index,1);
    }


    
}
```

I can see that my data is available in the subcomponent in the ngOnChanges method.

```js
import {Component,Input,Output,AfterViewInit, ViewChild,ChangeDetectionStrategy,EventEmitter,ViewEncapsulation } from '@angular/core';
import {MenuSearchService,MenuItem} from '../../services/menu-search-service';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Rx';
import { NarrowItDownComponent }  from '../../components/application/app.component';

@Component({
    selector: 'found-items',
    templateUrl: `app/components/founditems/founditems.html`,
 })
export class FoundItemsComponent  {
   @Input('items') private  items:MenuItem[];
   @Input('position') private  position:number;

    constructor() { 
    }

    remove() {
      console.log('remove'+this.position);
    }

   ngOnChanges(...args: any[]) {
        console.log('changing', args);
        console.log(this.items);
    }

}
```

The service code returning the data is :

```
getMatchedMenuItems(searchTerm: string): MenuItem[] {
var elements: MenuItem[] = [];
this.http.get(this.constantService.API_ENDPOINT + "/menu_items.json")
  .flatMap((response) => response.json()['menu_items'])
  .filter((menu_item) => menu_item.description.toLowerCase().indexOf(searchTerm) !== -1)

  .subscribe(

  (menu_item) => {
    console.log(menu_item);
    elements.push(new MenuItem(
      menu_item.id,
      menu_item.short_name,
      menu_item.name,
      menu_item.description,
      menu_item.price_small,
      menu_item.price_large,
      menu_item.small_portion_name,
      menu_item.large_portion_name));
  }

  ,
  function (error) { console.log("Error happened" + error) },
  function () { console.log("the subscription is completed") }
  );

console.log("el :" + elements);
return elements;
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found your issues, which would be that the data is not available yet when the child-component is rendered.

I think this should do the trick:

```
<div *ngIf="menuItems">
  <found-items [items]='menuItems'></found-items>
</div>
```

And remove from your parent:

```
@Output() menuItems:MenuItem[];
```

Output is only needed if you want to send some data back to the parent from the child.

Besides this, do as muzurBucu suggested:

```
ngOnInit() {
     this.menuSearchService.getMatchedMenuItems(yourSearchTerm)
         .subscribe(items => {
            // Your logic here
         });
}
```

And then I think you are good to go! :)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Yeah it's what I put in my comments. But all my attempts to use ngIf="menuItem" didn't work. I had to use ngIf="searchTerm" to bypass this. I would like a cleaner solution.

Answer (score 0):

`getMatchedMenuItems` is doing the subscribing itself. You are returning the list of elements that may or may not be populated since the observable pumps asynchronously.

What you need to do is have `getMatchedMenuItems` return the **Observable stream** (everything up to the subscribe).

Then, in your component, **once it's initialized**, you want to subscribe to this observable stream. So have your `NarrowItDownComponent` implement `OnInit`:

```
class NarrowItDownComponent implements OnInit {
```

Then create the subscription to the service's method that now returns an observable stream inside the `ngOnInit` method:

```
ngOnInit() {
     this.menuSearchService.getMatchedMenuItems(yourSearchTerm)
                           .subscribe(items => {
                               // Your logic here
                           });
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Even if I move the subscribe part in the NarrowItDownComponent.  I get the same behaviour. The subcomponent doesn't display anything. I pushed my new code on github.

Comment: Hello, in your app.html, you have single quotes around menuItems: <found-items [items]='menuItems'></found-items>  Can you try changing it to double quotes?

Comment: Tried simple and double quotes. It doesn't change anything.

Comment: I was able to got the subcomponent working by adding a ngIf on the searchTerm but if I try to use menuItem in the ngIf it's not working <items *ngIf="searchTerm" [items]='menuItems'>Loading...</items>

Comment: I am pretty sure it's because the ngIf on the searchTerm display the component when the list is loaded.

Comment: Pretty sure this one is related to my issue : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35901987/angular2-async-pipes-in-nested-ngif-using-ngrx